# Autoplay more than one item?

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

If the carousel shown 4 items, to set the autoplay replaced with 4 new items. Here the [demo](http://owlcarousel.owlgraphic.com/demos/autoplay.html) if you click on the item pagination, you can see the effect. But if we set auto play, then change only one item?

```
$(".owlcarousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1
        },
        600: {
            items: 3
        },
        1000: {
            items: 5
        }
    }
});
```

php / html code (cakephp)

```
    <?php $brands = $this -> requestAction('/brands'); ?>
<div class="featured-brands">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="owlcarousel">
            <?php foreach ($brands as $brand) {?>
                <div class="item"><?php echo $this->Html->image('brands/'.$brand['Brand']['id'].'/'.$brand['Brand']['image'],array('class'=>'img-responsive')); ?></div>
            <?php } ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd set `slideBy` to your item count:

```
$(".owlcarousel").owlCarousel({
    autoplay: true,
    margin: 10,
    nav: true,
    loop: true,
    responsive: {
        0: {
            items: 1,
            slideBy: 1
        },
        600: {
            items: 3,
            slideBy: 3
        },
        1000: {
            items: 5,
            slideBy: 5
        }
    }
});
```

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#slideby

Answer (score 3):

In Owl Carousel 2 you use the option: `slideBy:'page'` for sliding the entire "page" on autoPlay (or navigation buttons).

https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html